# C# app can't find types from a VB class library

Tags: c#, vb.net, class

I'm using a commercial C# application which is designed to allow the use of external plug-ins that the app loads at runtime. Basically, you create a class library that inherits and extends certain classes from the base app, and place your DLL in a specified place where the main app looks for it.  Most plug-ins written for this app use C# however I want to use VB instead, and I think this should be possible.

However, I get the following exceptions in the error log of the app:

> AssemblyLoader: Exception loading 'Thingamajig': 
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the
>   module cannot be loaded.
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes
>   (bool)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at AssemblyLoader.LoadAssemblies () [0x00000] in :0
>
> Additional information about this exception:
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Thingamajig.My.MyProject' from assembly 'Thingamajig,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Thingamajig.My.MyProject+ThreadSafeObjectProvider`1[T]' from assembly
>   'Thingamajig, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MyWebServices' from
>   assembly 'Thingamajig, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase' from assembly 'System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

"Thingamajig" is the name of my VB class. Both the C# app and the VB class reference .NET 3.5

I'm an amateur programmer, so go easy on me please. I *think* what is happening is my class library is referencing certain types (Ex: My.MyProject, System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase, MyWebServices) that the main app cannot find. I tried to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in the class library but Visual Studio comes back with an error stating that this component is "already automatically referenced by the build system".  My code for this "test" is very simple:

```
Imports System
Imports UnityEngine

Public Class Thingamajig
    Inherits PartModule
    Private _windowPosition As New Rect()

    Public Overrides Sub OnStart(state As StartState)
        If state <> StartState.Editor Then
            RenderingManager.AddToPostDrawQueue(0, AddressOf ondraw)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ondraw()
        If Me.vessel.active Then
            _windowPosition = GUILayout.Window(10, _windowPosition, AddressOf onwindow, "Hello World")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub onwindow(windowid As Integer)
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(GUILayout.Width(250.0F))
        GUILayout.Label("WOW! Isn't this Amazing?")
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal()
        GUI.DragWindow()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any ideas how to proceed?  Can I exclude the problematic types from the class library, or somehow tell the C# app where to find them?  Or, is what I am trying to do simply not possible?

**UPDATE:**

The answer below (compiling outside of the VS IDE) worked for my sample code that didn't really do much. Then I added some external libraries, one of which requires Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  I referenced that DLL during compilation and it compiles fine but when I run the app I get this in the log: 
 System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XObjectWrapper' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

Is this the same issue?  If i compile with Newtonsoft, why am I getting these errors?

Comment: Show us the code that loads the classes.

Comment: Try to set "Project Properties/Settings/Access Modifier" to "Friend".

Comment: @RobertHarvey the C# is a commercial app, no source code is available. It is designed to be extensible, but I am limited to modifying the VB class library only.

Comment: Hi. Xamarin has an implementation of Newtonsoft for Monotouch and Monodroid, it will work with Unity: http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triying to cheat Unity to use VB? hehehe.

I did something similar with Xamarin, to do it you must compile manually the DLL and remove the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference from your library (and then you will cringe with all the code you must replace to use only standard framework functions).

As a start point here is what we used to compile against MonoTouch.

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Vbc.exe  /sdkpath:(path to Unity framework) /noconfig   /verbose  /novbruntimeref   /imports:System,System.Reflection,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic /nowarn:42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022 /optionstrict+ /rootnamespace:(your namespace) /define:"_MyType=\"Empty\"" /reference:(all your needed libraries) /target:library "(path to source code)\*.vb"`

Comment: there is not **that** much to be missed in the VB Namespace...when you are done "cringing", you can revel in how C#-like your code looks.

Comment: @Plutonix Are you sure? did you know that even comparing an string uses Microsoft.VisualBasic in VB? I am not the one who was programming in VB on the case I exposed, but I remember my partner tearing his air apart because all the code he had to rewrite...

Comment: The first thing I do on a new project is to remove it.  As for strings, there is `System.String` and a `VisualBasic.Strings` which is different. The VB one exposes all those old functions like Asc, Chr, Len etc which in some cases just calls the related `System.String` function/method. `StrComp` would require the VB namespace, but `String.Compare` is just as powerful, if not more so.

Comment: I did not say it can't be done, but seriously, for a standard vb program, how many 'If mystring = "avalue" Then...' lines should be replaced?

Comment: that line will compile fine without the VB Namespace and without change. There **are** cases where the output will call VB specific things via CompilerServices, but since it is part of the NET framework we dont care - they will be found and used as needed. What including a reference to the VB Namespace does is allow you to use those old functions in code like Fix, Hex(), Str, Val, Format(), Mid() and others like those mentioned above.

Comment: Removing the reference from the project does nothing, it adds the reference. the key there is the /novbruntimeref for compiling, after that, if you try to compile you will get: `error BC35000: Requested operation is not available because the runtime library function 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString' is not defined. If a = "" Then a = "a" Compile error: 1 error`

Comment: as I said, it will add some things it needs as it needs them via compiler services.  for the purposes of using Unity or the other tool, simply removing the ref wont work (ie I agree).  "for a standard vb program" as you put it, the VB Namespace isnt needed for the IDE to accept and compile `If mystring = "avalue"` - it links back to VB but we dont usually care. Removing it **does** prevent code using Val, Str, StrComp etc from compiling because those **do** need a VB reference.  Apples and Oranges as to whether you are talking about the specific case as in the OP, or simply in general.

Comment: Are we talking in general or are we answering a question? Did I said he will cringe always or just when compiling for Unity using that command line and removing the vb runtime reference? I can admit i was dissafortunate when said "comparing an string uses Microsoft.VisualBasic", it should be "comparing an string uses Visual Basic runtime"

Comment: This worked as described, and will hold me over until I bite the bullet and move from VB to C# (something I should have done long ago). Thanks.

Comment: I just edited my post to reflect an addition error I ran into. Thanks